# Close dropdown menu when clicking menu sub item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked at and tried several recommendations from other discussions on here but I can't seem to get my menu working.

I am working on a parallax scrolling webpage and I have a mobile dropdown menu that works perfectly, but I need it to collapse the menu when you click a menu item.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="parallax-menu">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#slide1">Solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide3">Career-Readiness</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide5">Community</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide7">Professors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slide9">Value</a></li>
                <li><a href="#slide11">Future</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background: red;
}

/*Mobile menu icon*/
.icon-menu{font-size:30px}
#parallax-menu{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   border-right: none;
   float: left;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
#parallax-menu ul {
  display:table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
  align-content: center;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
#parallax-menu ul li {
list-style: none;
  float: left;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
#parallax-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
#parallax-menu li:hover a {
    background: #fcad26;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s .05s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s .05s;
  -o-transition: all .5s .05s;
  transition: all .5s .05s;
  color: #000;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
#parallax-menu li:hover ul a {
    background: #fcad26;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#parallax-menu ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#parallax-menu ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
#parallax-menu li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #fcad26;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
#parallax-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
#parallax-menu li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
#parallax-menu li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
#parallax-menu ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  #parallax-menu ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
#parallax-menu li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
#parallax-menu ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Working CodePen:
[CodePen Version](http://codepen.io/tagriffith/pen/WbaKOR)

I am able to open and close the dropdown menu by clicking on the menu header, but I need it on the menu item as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to delete code with input+label and use only jQuery with html elements.

```
 $('.show-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#menu a').on('click', function() {
    $('#menu').removeClass('active');
});
```

**Please check all code in Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y5aa1p61/

Actually, You need to fix your CSS too. Don't forget to check differences between codes if you use it.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was wanting it to do. I still need to clean up the CSS before putting it into action. I quickly threw that together today to try to figure the dropdown menu.

Separate question though: I have two NAV menus on the same page and I selected the SECOND menu CSS with the ID tag (<nav id="#parallax-menu">). One thing that constantly comes up when I check my CSS through CodeLint is the "Don't use IDs in selectors". How else do you select a second nav without the selector?

Comment: You can use only class, why you need IDs? this is jQuery, you can select element how you want to :) In todays CSS everybody uses class, ID is for some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it that way and your UL is being expanded when you open the submenu you can cheat a little bit with css and go like this

```
#element{
height:100px;
transition:0.5s;
}

#subMenuUL:active #element{
height:0;
}
```

**Note** the element you want to hide that way has to be a child of the element that will be clicked, or at least has to be the element itself
and with that transition you will even have a closing animation